# Javascript not working from js file but working on codePen

Tags: javascript, html

Javascript doesn't seem to be working when placed in a seperate js folder. not sure what the problem is as on Codepen it seems to work

This is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
        <title></title>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="Mainpage">
                <div class="TimeButtons">
                    <button class="btn btn-info" id="start">Start</button>
                    <h3 id='timer'>1:00</h3>
                    <button class="btn btn-info" id="add">+</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-info" id="sub">-</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-warning" id="restart">Restart</button>
                </div>
                <h1>Lab 17</h1>

                <div class="cams">
                    <iframe src="url naar blue iris" style="background-color: grey;"></iframe>
                </div>

                <div class="hints">
                    <div class="puzzelheader">
                        <h4>Hints</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>


                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="customhintsend">Versturen</button>

                        <button style="display: none;" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="customhinthide">Verbergen</button>
                        <p class="WeergevenHint"><b>Word nu weergeven:</b> <span id="ActieveHint"></span>

                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="puzzleflow">
                    <div class="Puzzels">fdsf</div>
                    <div class="Puzzels">fdsf</div>
                    <div class="Puzzels">fdsf</div>

                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

and my js code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var oldTimeVal = 0;
  var oldSecVal = 0;
  var time = 1;
  var sec = 0;
  var addIntervals;
  var countdown;
  function updateTime() {
    if(sec < 10) $('#timer').text(time + ":0" + sec);
    else $('#timer').text(time + ":" + sec);
  }
  function updateInc() {
  }
  function add() {
    time += 1;
    updateTime();
    if(countdown) updateInc();
  }
  function sub() { 
    time -= 1;
    if(time <= 0) time = 1;
    updateTime();
    if(countdown) updateInc();
  }
  function loop() {
    sec -= 1;
    if(sec < 0) {
      time -= 1;
      sec = 59;
    }
    if(time == 0 && sec <= 0) {
      clearInterval(countdown);
      countdown = undefined;
    }
    updateTime();
  }
  function startLoop() {
    if(time == 0 && sec == 0) time = 0;
    updateTime();
    countdown = setInterval(loop, 1000);
    oldTimeVal = time;
    oldSecVal = sec;
  }
  $('#start').click(startLoop);
  $('#add').click(add).mousedown(function() {
    addIntervals = setInterval(add, 250);
  }).mouseup(function() {
    clearInterval(addIntervals);
  });
  $('#sub').click(sub).mousedown(function() {
    addIntervals = setInterval(sub, 250);
  }).mouseup(function() {
    clearInterval(addIntervals);
  });
  $('#restart').click(function() {
    clearInterval(countdown);
    countdown = undefined;
    time = oldTimeVal;
    sec = oldSecVal;
    updateTime();
  });
});
```

and the layout of the folder:

[image]

The code seemed to work in Codepen but for some reason it doens't want to work if I localhost it or when I try it in Dreamweaver.

Comment: Look in the console and you'll most probably see that `$` is not a function. I'd assume that you forgot to include jQuery and codePen has it in dependencies / resources. (It would also help to see the pen).

Comment: welp that was it. I didn't add Jquery. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are missing `jQuery` and `boostrap` js files. Please add those js files. First, add `jQuery` then add `bootstrap` js file, and then your `main.js` file.

With the following script, it will add a script from CDN. You can download and add it to your js folder. Make sure you use the same version for both the `bootstrap.min.css` and `bootstrap.min.js` files.

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-oP6HI9z1XaZNBrJURtCoUT5SUnxFr8s3BzRl+cbzUq8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<script
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```